# VHDL: best way to pass testcase name string into simulator from run script?

Tags: vhdl

In verilog, I can pass the name of a testcase into the simulation by using the standard verilog simulator flag:

```
+define+TESTCASE=\"mytestcase.txt\"
```

Then, in the verilog code I can do something like this:

```
//Verilog
fid = $fopen(`TESTCASE);
```

However, in VHDL, I'm not don't know the best way to achieve a similar effect.   Basically I want my run a shell script to invoke the VHDL simulator and compile my VHDL source, but to somehow convey the name of the testcase i want to run as a VHDL string external to the VHDL simulator.  For Example:

```
$ perl RunVhdlSimulation.pl --testcase hello1.txt
```

Then the perl script invokes the VHDL simulator and somehow tells it to read the file call "hello1.txt".  In the VHDL code I would have some code that looks like this to pick up the name of the testcase file.

```
--VHDL
process
    --where testcase is set by script to be "hello1.txt"
    constant  testfile   :string := testcase; 
begin
...
end process;
```

Now, I'm wondering how to achieve this end...I'm thinking that I could create some type of file and compile it with my vhdl code to tell it this information.  I'm just having a debate about what's the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create your own solution the command line option is the way to go. Simulators support a limited set of types but all I've seen support strings.

You can also use VUnit (http://vunit.github.io) which provides the functionality you're looking for. The GHDL command line option was actually added to support VUnit (https://sourceforge.net/p/ghdl-updates/tickets/37/).

Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors for VUnit.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

my %params  = ();

GetOptions(
    'help'       => \$opt_help,
    'go'         => \$opt_go,
    'testcase=s' => \$params{testcase}
); 

create_testcase_pkg(%params);

# RUN SIMULATION HERE

exit 1;

sub create_testcase_pkg(%) {
    my $params      = %_;
    my $pkg_name    = "sim_testcase_pkg";
    my $pkg_file    = "./${pkg_name}.vhd";

    print "creating file: $pkg_file\n";

    $testcase = $params{testcase};

    print "TESTCASE: $testcase\n";

    open(F, ">$pkg_file") || die("cannot create: ${pkg_file}");
    print F "package ${pkg_name} is\n";
    print F "\n";
    print F "    constant testcase :string := \"$testcase\";\n";
    print F "end package;\n";
    close(F);
}
```

Comment: That seems extreme. Simulators allow you to pass values to generics in the design. For modelsim and ActiveHDL it is -g passed to vsim/asim. Something like vsim -gtestcase="Test Number 1"

Comment: ghdl has the command line option also. IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.2 Elaboration of a design hierarchy "An implementation may allow, but is not required to allow, a design entity at the root of a design hierarchy to have generics and ports. If an implementation allows these top-level interface objects, it may restrict their allowed forms "...", and, in the case of interface objects, their allowed types and modes in an implementation-defined manner."  This likely came from vendor(s) participating in standardization effort whose product(s) didn't provide the feature (text added in -1993).

Comment: A code generator can also suffer from portability issues. If your script is perl it appears to have assumptions about either environment or version (or both).